# Altering data that is returned by a SqlCommand before binding it to a Listview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to alter a data from a Select SqlCommand before binding it to the asp:listview? Here is the code:

```
void getAudit()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    com.Connection = con;
    com.CommandText = "SELECT a.AuditRID, e.EmployeeID, e.LastName, e.FirstName, a.TimeStamp, " +
        "a.Event, a.Description FROM AuditLogs a INNER JOIN Employee e ON a.EmployeeID " +
        "= e.EmployeeID ORDER BY a.AuditRID DESC";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Audit");
    lvAudit.DataSource = ds;
    lvAudit.DataBind();
    con.Close();
```

Description column returns an encrypted data from the Database and i would like to decrypt it before binding it to an asp:listview namely the lvAudit in my front end. Is this possible?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233701.aspx

Comment: as i read thru the link you commented i saw that it expects the table to be a DataTable but the problem is that i dont use DataTable

Comment: You do use `DataTable` as a member of `DataSet`. As to OP, you can modify each row in `lvAudit_ItemDataBound` event handler.